# Could not update in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

```
public function orgPurokEdit($orgId, $purok, $newPurokName)
    {
        $updated = Data::where('org_id', $orgId)
        ->where('purok', $purok)
        ->update(['purok' => $newPurokName]);

        if($updated){
            $this->success = true;
        }else
        {
            $this->errors = "Not updated";
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => $this->success,
            'errors' => $this->errors
        ]);
    }
```

This is the code however it was not updating any data. Is there something wrong with this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is it returning `true` or `Not updated`?

Comment: Have you added the column to fillable array ?

Comment: It returns response.success = false

Comment: @SagarGautam yes

Comment: Have you checked `$orgId` value ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? have you checked $orgId, $purok values, what are these?

Comment: What about $orgId its primary key ?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Update returns **the number of rows that has been modified** and not if the query has been executed correctly or not, In other words, If there are no rows matching ur condition the update function will return `0` even if it didn't raise an exception or error.

So to make sure there are rows matching your condition inspect how much rows you got by and let's us know:

```
$count = Data::where('org_id', $orgId)->where('purok', $purok)->count();
```

if it's greater than 0 then your update query will certainly work.

and a better way to put code will be:

```
public function orgPurokEdit($orgId, $purok, $newPurokName)
    {
        $query = Data::where('org_id', $orgId)->where('purok', $purok);

        if($query->count() == 0){
            //There are no entries to update
        }else
        {
            $updated = $query->update(['purok' => $newPurokName]);
            // $updated."rows has been updated";
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps :)